# Recommended reading to learn Gherkin

Tags: testing, rspec, bdd, specflow, gherkin

I wish to learn **Gherkin** so I can use it with **specflow**; I am looking for a document I can read on the train e.g. print out on paper.

All I can find on the web is short disconnected descriptions that don’t tell a story and require lots of clicking between web pages to read.

(I don't mind buying a good if it has lots of good **Gherkin** content in it)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The RSpec book is a great book to introduce some of the concepts of BDD, Rspec(as a .net dev you should check out MSpec) and Cucumber which is a based on Gherkin.

The best free printable resource is the awesome [cuke4ninja](https://github.com/davedf/cuke4ninja) which has a PRINTABLE pdf (follow instructions in README.md on github to create).

[image: NINJA Cucumber!]

There is a BNF definition https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/gherkin/wiki/BNF if you are that way inclined.

There's a [Cucumber book](http://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book) out now too

**EDIT**: It looks cuke4ninja.com isn't what it was anymore (it's now some dating site) but the site is still kept on github. The link above has been changed.

Comment: I don't know if the site has changed since you made this comment, but I'd like to add that http://www.cuke4ninja.com/ is a dating advice site!

Comment: I'll ping the author.

Comment: it's backed up on github https://github.com/davedf/cuke4ninja

Answer (score 6):

I've used [Writing Features - Gherkin Language](http://docs.behat.org/guides/1.gherkin.html) as the recommended introduction for newcomers at work, and it has worked out really good

Answer (score 5):

I would start with the official [Gherkin Language Page](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/gherkin)  and work your way from there. It is a broad enough overview to get the major components and show people that it's really just a human-readable, business language for getting requirements down.

From there I would expand to the [The Official Cucumber Tutorials](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tutorials-and-Related-Blog-Posts) or checkout [this blog post](http://bjarte.com/post/228763457) for more insight.

If you're looking for something to hold, you should pick up [The RSpec Book](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/achbd/the-rspec-book) which covers Gherkin and Cucumber; the language is so terse that it can be quickly covered and learned, so you're unlikely to find a book dedicated to just Gherkin.

Comment: How can I print something useful out from these, they are not desing as documents to be read "of-line"

Comment: The Gherkin homepage I provided as well as these pages could be printable and cover the majority of the information you would need to get started. Honestly the language is so small it won't warrant it's own book: https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/wiki/Feature-Introduction , https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/wiki/Given-When-Then

Comment: pages have moved to https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Feature-Introduction and https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Given-When-Then

Answer (score 4):

This is a guide I've put together from a few years of working with Cucumber and Gherkin

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1pkhePZ7eaOWskai3gmopa4Sp6o88r1kGZITVRs_PN7Q/pub

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for something that is offline I cannot recommend The RSpec Book (http://www.pragprog.com/titles/achbd/the-rspec-book) enough. It's a great book and introduces not only BDD, but also Cucumber and Gherkin.

On how to write great Gherkin I have found this article very useful: http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2009/15-expert-tips-for-using-cucumber/

Good luck